# Modal window/Pop up with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need to use any script for pop-up like jquery or fancy-box to open a page in a modal window here in the calendar when you click on event, I open in a fancy-box, but I need the user to see the URL of the event http://www.illuminationsworld.com/events

A very good example of that is [behance.net](http://www.behance.net/) if you click on any project it will open in a nice modal window/pop-up and you can copy the URL of the project, and if you click outside the project window, you will get back to the home page with its original URL

Comment: It's a new div, positioned to center of screen. You can fill it with ajax or just transfer elements from page to that div. You can wrap that new div with some kind of "hit-box" that stretches over entire screen and add onclick function that will delete both new divs. It is not that hard to make it on your own. I hope that this few guidelines are helpful.

Comment: you didn't read my question thoroughly ! or go to behance.net to check, please check

Comment: I did. What do you want to do exactly? You have a fancy-box and you want to show URL of clicked event there?